# Where was Charlotte Hancock, usually of Lewannick, Cornwall, for the 1851 Census?

Tags: 19th-century, cornwall, census-records

My 2nd great grandparents **Charlotte Hancock** and Edward Sleep married on 22 Sep 1853 at Lewannick, Cornwall, England, and two years later they emigrated to South Australia.  Charlotte was recorded as being of Full Age, with no occupation, residing at Lewannick, with her father being William, a Labourer.  Edward is also recorded as being a Labourer.

I believe Charlotte was christened on 18 Apr 1830 at South Petherwin, Cornwall, to parents William and Anne Hancock.

She appears in the 1841 Census at Lewannick in a household of:

- William Handcock 39 Labourer
- Ann Handcock 35
- Jane Handcock 13
- **Charlotte Handcock** 11
- Kitty Handcock 9
- Elizabeth Handcock 5
- William Handcock 1

In the 1851 Census at Lewannick her parents and some siblings have been located in a household of:

- William Handcock 50 Farm Labourer
- Ann Handcock 47
- Catharine Handcock   19
- Elizabeth Handcock   13
- Meninah Handcock 4 [christened Marian but spelled uniquely in every census]
- Jane Binney 80 [Charlotte's maternal grandmother]

However, I am unable to locate Charlotte.  I am assuming that she will be working as a servant of some kind not too far from Lewannick but I am yet to stumble across her.

I have subscriptions to both Ancestry and FindMyPast to look at suggested records, so does anyone know of a candidate record for Charlotte in the 1851 Census?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used FindMyPast to do another search and found Charlotte!

I searched in the 1851 Census for Charlotte Hancock born 1830 +/-1 in Cornwall and from St Budeaux in Devon out jumped this household:

- John Handcock 39 Inn Keeper born in North Hill, Cornwall
- Frances Handcock 38
- Jane Handcock 6
- John Handcock 5
- Mary Ann Handcock 3
- William Handcock 1
- Sharlotte Handcock 20 Unmarried Servant born in South Petherwin, Cornwall
- Jane Freeman 19
- Thomas Taylor 27
- Richard Martin 44
- Betsey Martin 54

Charlotte's grandfather was called John Handcock, and while she had two uncles of the same name, one was born in 1777 (and presumably died young), and the other born in 1796 also seems too old, so I think she may here be living with and working for a first cousin.